# No Mouse-Up for Chrome on Ubuntu VM; other apps fine

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, virtualbox, mouse

**TLDR:** I have an Ubuntu VM with the latest VirtualBox, and guest additions, and Chrome (installed from APT: `google-chrome-stable`). Mouse integration seems broken; I can't move tabs around, nor get any mouse-overs. Upgrading/downgrading (VirtualBox and reinstalling guest additions and the extension pack) doesn't help. Now what?

**Backstory:** I recreated my VM about a month ago (upgrading to 14.04 was a disaster because of GPU tearing). Around that time, I noticed that mouse integration seems broken **in Chrome only**. Symptoms include:

- Can't move tabs around in the tab bar
- Can't see notes (Google spreadsheets)
- Can't see mouse-overs for anything in Chrome

This only affects Chrome; FireFox is fine. I also upgraded/downgraded VirtualBox (including reinstalling the extension pack and guest additions) for the last four versions (4.3.20 to 4.3.26).

Disabling mouse integration works. I also tried reinstalling Chrome several times, to no avail.

I deleted and recreated my VM, and still see this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following is taken from (solution #129)

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=456222#makechanges

```
solution for this:
- sudo vim /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
- change this line:
  Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U
  to
  Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --touch-devices=123 %U
```

This fixed my mouse-up for chrome. I am on

- Windows 7 host
- VM Ubuntu 14.04.2
- chrome-stable  version 41.0.2272.101 (64-bit)

It did not work immediately for me. Try closing everything and then trying the mouse-up on chrome again.